# Img tag occupying all the page

Tags: css

I am having a company logo that I want to set towards top right. My image is looking nice only when width is 300px and height is 500px.

When I change my div or img tag position the image expands. Using span tag instead of div would be right idea ?

I have tried couple of solutions in stackoverflow but none of them worked.

```
div #container{
position: relative;
}

img #img1{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Show your HTML and CSS. Even better, if you reproduce the problem in a fiddle.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev okay I will see if i can do that! thx!

Comment: Your **CSS selector** is incorrect remove spaces `img#img1`,`div #container`, set either width or height for the image would be a solution

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set the width and height of your image to be 300 and 500 respectively. Try doing so in your css with the image, or even in html, with the simple attributes `width="300" height="500"`. Hope it helps.